# Cloud Vision with Cloud Functions: Exception occurred in retry method that was not classified as transient

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-vision

I've been getting the following error from a Cloud function that uses the Cloud Vision API:

```
Error: 1 CANCELLED: The operation was cancelled.
  at Object.callErrorFromStatus (/srv/functions/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:30:26)
  at Http2CallStream.call.on (/srv/functions/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:96:33)
  at Http2CallStream.emit (events.js:203:15)
  at Http2CallStream.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:466:23)
  at process.nextTick (/srv/functions/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:100:22)
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
  code: 1,
  details: 'The operation was cancelled.',
  metadata:
  Metadata {
   internalRepr:
    Map {
      'google.rpc.debuginfo-bin' => [Array],
      'grpc-status-details-bin' => [Array] },
   options: {} },
  note:
 'Exception occurred in retry method that was not classified as transient' }
```

The code is as follows:

```
const vision = require('@google-cloud/vision');
const client = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient();
const [result] = await client.textDetection(`gs://${process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT}.appspot.com/${fileName}`)
  .catch((err: any) => {
    return db.doc(event.ref.path).update({ status: 'error' });
  });
```

Not sure if this has to do with the problems Firebase had today?

Comment: I have the same issue with Google Cloud Functions (without firebase.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by adding using `google-gax` version 1.15.2 and adding the following resolution:

```
"resolutions": {
  "google-gax": "1.15.2"
 },
```